# how should web site display other page and allow users to rate that page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a web page that shows a user an Amazon page, and allow users on my site to rate whether or not the link was useful.  I was hoping to use iframes, but it seems that Amazon prevents their site from being embedded inside a frame.  Since pop-ups are frequently blocked, how can I send a user to another site, and still get them to provide a rating (feedback) to my site?

note: I am not trying to gather ratings from users for amazon content, but rather how well it is based on my site's content and how the amazon product relates.  Another scenario might be if I link to a youtube video... I basically want to know if they found it useful.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would it be acceptable to simply have the link open in a new tab, and rely on the user returning to your site's tab?

Answer (score 0):

Try an object tag:

```
<object data="http://amazon.com"></object>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/KMwFB/

But I'm not sure Amazon would like that.

Comment: I just tested an iframe in jsfiddle and it worked too?